# How to pass returned function value to ejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

I want to pass the returned function value to ejs engine template but instead I am getting "undefined".

I have file with a couple of functions - util.js, and in that file I have:

```
var models = require('../../models');
var UserModel = models.user;
var FotoModel = models.photographer;

function whoAmI(req, res){
    FotoModel.findOne({
        where: {
            IdUser: req.user.IdUser
        }
    }).then(function (foto) {
        if(!foto){
            return "Client"
        }else{
            return "Photographer"
        }
    });
}

module.exports ={
    whoAmI: whoAmI,
}
```

And I have a file named controller.js:

```
var util = require('../models/util.js');
var exports = module.exports = {}

exports.profile = function(req, res){

    res.render("profile", {
                name: req.user.Name,
                lastName: req.user.LastName,
                login: req.user.Login,
                email: req.user.Email,
                ifClient : util.whoAmI(req, res)
    });

}
```

I would like to send to a variable "ifClient", returned value from function "whoAmI" when rendering the view in ejs. When I am doing like that I'm getting "undefined". How can I do this?

Comment: the function is async. You have to fetch da data and then render the view. you can pass callback and render inside whoIAm function or use async await.

Comment: Ok, thank you @user2693928, now it is working!